# In multisite environment which is the most Popular blog?

Tags: multisite

In a wordpress multisite - selfhosted environment:-
how to know which blog has highest number of visitors ?
how to know which blog has highest number of comments and posts ?

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics can help you track down the blog visits.

This plugin may help:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/generalstats/

I'm working on a most comments plugin for release as well.

So far, I can;t think of any plugin off the top of my head that specifically says this blog has the most posts - though the number of posts per blog is visible in the admin area (Sites menu)

Comment: Curious to hear if you have made progress on a "most comments" plugin for Multisite.